# Create React App creates *.chunk.css when I want them as inline style tag

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm using CRA2 for building my project. There are some places with css import, like

```
import 'common.css'
```

or library csses, like

```
import 'librabry/dist/lib.min.css'
```

I want them to be included as inline  tag, instead css files are created and regarding to WebTool Audit they are render blocking stylesheets.

How to import stylesheets files and move them as inline  tag with create react app ?

Comment: May i ask why you would want that? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: It is suggested by Lighthouse Audit and if I'm not mistaken, less requests are better ?

Comment: But if my memory doesn't play tricks on me, CRA puts *all* your CSS in *one* big `.css` file when you actually build the production app. So it's just one request to get the CSS. Maybe there is a tool that does what you want during the build process (insert all the CSS from the files into inline `style` attributes), but i don't know one, sorry.

Comment: Unfortunetaly CRA2 creates separate css files for each import, that is why I want them to be inline, especially when they are actually not that big.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?